# How to write Custom time to blob metadata GCS object?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to write 'Custom time' field to blob metadata of GCS object.
My code that doesn't work, just do nothing

```
import datetime
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
folder_name = ''

bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_name)

for blob in blobs:
    blob.custom_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the best of my understanding, the `custom_time` is read only. See https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.custom_time

You might would prefer to work with the `metadata` property - https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.metadata - which can be set (as a dictionary, for example) in addition to retrieval.

Additional description is here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-metadata , and an example is here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-set-object-metadata-python

Comment: thanks. The main goal was to set automatically object deletion, it based on custom time. Not metadata. The field can be modified from ui, but not api. Why?..

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot delete or decrease the time once it is set.

I ended up figuring this out

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
blob.custom_time = current_time
blob.patch()
```